# Воспроизводить аудио при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android, аудио

Есть коллекция, которая хранит названия аудио

```
songs = new ArrayList<>();
songs.add("song_1.ogg");
songs.add("song_2.ogg");
songs.add("song_3.ogg");
songs.add("song_4.ogg");
songs.add("song_5.ogg");
songs.add("song_6.ogg");
```

Есть метод, который проигрывает аудио в зависимости от того, какое значение передано.

```
private void playSong(int i) {
    String mSong = songs.get(i);
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getAssets().openFd("sounds/songs/" + mSong);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        mp.setLooping(false);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Есть кнопка, по нажатию на который нужно проигрывать аудио так: Нажали один раз начинается проигрывание аудио из коллекции song_1.ogg, нажали второй раз первое остановилось началось проигрывание аудио song_2.ogg и т.д. до аудио song_6.ogg. Если нажать еще раз, то опять проигрывать аудио song_1.ogg и т.д.

Как это реализовать? Логику просто подскажите. А то я сделала так, и у меня начинают играть несколько аудио если я несколько раз нажму на кнопку

счетчик

```
private int counter = 0;
```

блок case

```
case R.id.btnMusic:
    if (counter == 0) {
        play(0);
    } else if (counter == 1) {
        mp.release();
        play(1);
    } else if (counter == 2) {
        mp.release();
        play(2);
    } else if (counter == 3) {
        mp.release();
        play(3);
    } else if (counter == 4) {
        mp.release();
        play(4);
    } else if (counter == 5) {
        mp.release();
        play(5);
    }
    break;
```

Сам метод

```
private void play(int i) {
    counter = i;
    String mSong = songs.get(counter);
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getAssets().openFd("sounds/songs/" + mSong);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        mp.setLooping(false);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Так вы Виктор или Виктория? Определитесь как то :)

Comment: А мое имя не видно?

Comment: Видно, конечно. Но вы пишете от себя в мужском роде, а имя вроде женское :) Ваше дело конечно.

Comment: Ну я сразу исправила свою ошибку. Мы ведь люди и можем допустить ошибку.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вставьте в методе `play()`, что-то типа:

```
if(mp.isPlaying()) {
   mp.stop();
   mp.reset();
}
```

А сам плеер надо создавать 1 раз, а то вы создаете при каждом обращении новый экземпляр плеера.

Comment: ошибку выдает в строке где источник указывается java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                          at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1153)

Comment: Плеер где создаете? Надо создавать не в методе `play()`

Comment: в onCreate перенесла создание

Comment: поменяйте `release()` на `reset()`

Comment: все равно. Я прописала ваше условие после строчки mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());

Comment: Ну надо же до того как

Comment: почитайте [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509588/illegalstateexception-in-mediaplayer-set-datasource-method)

Comment: спасибо, все получилось. Я не знала про то что есть метод reset у плеера, но теперь буду знать.